# Where do I put resource files for C++ projects?

Tags: c++, project, project-structure

I just finished my first project of decent size, and I wanted a way to make it more organized (previously I had just been throwing all the `.cpp` files into a single folder). I looked around online and found that most projects use something similar to this, which I mimicked:

```
+-- src
    +-- blah.cpp

+-- res
    +-- image.png

+-- include
    +-- blah.hpp

+-- bin
    +-- blah.exe
    +-- something.dll

+-- README.md
```

The thing is, I need to access `image.png` in my program. I'm using Sublime Text, so I'm building the project from the "root" folder, which means that in my code, I write something like `Image image("res/image.png")`. However, when I go to click on the executable, it can't find `image.png`.

I've looked around on GitHub, and all the projects are either too small for it to be organized like this, or too large for me to figure out what they did to circumvent this issue. I have also seen people copy the `res` folder into the `bin` folder, which I think defeats the purpose of having separate `bin` and `res` folders in the first place.

Comment: With the Qt  framework I create a src, Include and rc folder for each target (library or executable). For how the libraries and executables are organized I have a hierarchy of folders.

Comment: You can either change the *current directory* or use a proper relative path like `../res/image.png`?

Answer (score 0):

Resources can be embedded in the binary and used with the resource compiler.

Or when you package your distributable, you have locations where you expect to find the resources.

You will need to load the image differently, but directly from the resources makes it easier to copy your executable to a new system

Check out [LoadResource:Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadresource)